# How to toggle the background color of a div in Rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Rails 4. How could I toggle the background color of a list item?

Here is my code so far. However, when I refresh the page, the color disappears.

application.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".myitem").on("click", function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("changecolor");
    }); 
});
```

index.html.erb

```
<% @ideas.each do |idea| %>
    <li class="myitem"><%= idea.description %></li>
<% end %>
```

.css file:

```
.changecolor {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

What should I do next?

Comment: rails wont save color state for your div unless you save it manually to database or cookies

Comment: Should I then continue by generating a 'highlight: boolean' migration for the ideas table, creating a route and a controller for the 'highlight' action etc...

Comment: it depends if you want use only 1 type of class. I'd recommend put string with class name instead of boolean. This will give you more flexibility and might be in future you want to customize it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on a few things you should save it in your cookies, session, or database.

Cookie: If you want it to only affect the computer of the user who made the change, and don't need the value elsewhere.

Session: If you want it to only affect the computer of the user who made the change, but you might want to use it somewhere else in your code besides JS.

Database: If you want it to be saved for everyone! Or just one user, but want to ensure it's saved more long term and is the same even if a user is on different computers.

All of these options have some overlap, but this is basically the gist. The session and cookies don't require much code, but the database requires a migration.

Answer (score 1):

Next - you should save your color class to database, and assing class to your div using database value

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: question was: "What should I do next?", i've answered. If you dont like it, leave your own